# Crear un ejecutable de python para un sistema de 32bits

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, ejecutar

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma, al igual que pyinstaller para crear un exe de 64 bits de Python, otra forma para sistemas de 32 bits.

Tengo este proyecto y otros que también quisiera poder ejecutar en equipos de 32 bits, pero desconozco la forma de hacerlo.

https://github.com/Xaival/Programar-apagado

Ya he probado a convertirlo en un equipo de 32 bits con PyInstaller (Se puede ver en la imagen) y auto-py-to-exe (No he conseguido llegar a instalarlo).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otra parte, ya he comprobado y el programa de python ejecutándolo directamente desde el archivo .py funciona correctamente.

Comment: Instalate Python de 32 bits, pyinstaller en dicha version y compila tu programa.

Answer (score 0):

### ¡Buen dia!

No puedes convertir un ejecutable de python para un sistema de `32bits` si te encuentras usando una versión de python igual a `64bits`. esto porque una de las características de Python rige en ser un lenguaje *`interpretado`*, esto quiere decir que es interpretado en tiempo de ejecución. Aqui una lectura mas profunda sobre el tema [¿Qué significa que python es un lenguaje interpretado? - Quora](https://es.quora.com/Qu%C3%A9-significa-que-python-es-un-lenguaje-interpretado)

### **Solución**:

Para compilar el código en una  arquitectura de `32bits` Debes instalar python para `32bits` e instalar nuevamente las librerias que te encuentras usando pero esta vez las librerias deben ser compatibles con el interprete de `32bits` para que ambas instalaciones tengan el mismo conjunto de paquetes instalados.

Comment: Ya intenté lo que dices, pero PyInstaller no se ejecutaba correctamente, igualmente voy a tratar de volverlo a intentar.

Cuando lo intente te digo

Comment: No me dejaba adjuntar la imagen por aquí, así que he editado la pregunta y puesto al final eso.

Comment: Pudiste solucionar el problema?

Comment: No, no he podido.